# Comando findstr no cmd

Tags: cmd, bat

Olá, Fiz uma bat para imprimir uma informação de dentro de um arquivo xml (PosVersion.xml) só que ele só me dá a informação da linha que eu pesquisei e não me fala de qual máquina esse arquivo pertence. E eu quero que apareça o nome da máquina a qual pertença o arquivo junto com a informação que preciso dele ( a linha "COEBuild"). Estou usando o código abaixo.

```
@Echo off for /F "tokens=" %%A in (ServerList.txt) do ( findstr "COEBuild" \%%A\c$\NewPos61\PosData\POSVersion.xml >log.txt ) pause*
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo parecido com isso:

```
@Echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in (ServerList.txt) do (
echo %%A:>>log.txt
findstr "COEBuild" \\%%A\c$\NewPos61\PosData\POSVersion.xml>>log.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: Obrigado !!! Deu certo.